# GroupBy() running extremely slow

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq, group-by

I have a table in my database which has a date field (`VisitDate`). When I execute the following SQL query, I receive the results in **1 second**:

```
select year(VisitDate), month(visitDate) 
from GABrowser 
group by year(VisitDate), month(visitDate)
```

However, in my ASP.Net code (in Visual Basic), the follow takes 12 seconds to execute:

```
Dim stats = db.GABrowsers.GroupBy(Function(s) New With {s.VisitDate.Value.Year, s.VisitDate.Value.Month})

'(Takes 12 seconds to enter in the For loop)
For Each stat In stats 

Next
```

I don't know why it takes so long. It's causing my web pages to load extremely slow.

Comment: Have to see what SQL Server is actually doing. Can you run SQL profiler to see which commands your app sends to SQL Server? Then you'll see what is running and for how long.

Comment: Create Clustered Index for the VisitDate and post your SQL query with EF Profiler

Comment: I never heard of SQL profiler. Where do I run this?

Answer (score 3):

The SQL query and the LINQ query are not equivalent.

The SQL query only returns `year(VisitDate)` and `month(visitDate)`. `GroupBy` in LINQ is different though, it returns *full entities* that are grouped by the grouping condition.

In the LINQ result you'll see `db.GABrowsers` entities in groups of identical `s.VisitDate.Value.Year` and `s.VisitDate.Value.Month`. You'll see that the SQL query generated by the LINQ statement is much wider (in fields) than the first SQL query.

Besides that (a larger SQL result set) it takes time for EF to process the data from the database and materialize entity objects.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you posted the equivalent LINQ query.

Comment: Just add `.Select(Function(g) g.Key)` at the end of the query.

Comment: @IvanStoev Not sure if OP actually wants the same result from the LINQ statement, or that they tried the SQL statement *assuming* it was equivalent. Would be interesting to see what happens in the `For` loop. Of course, if they want to reproduce the SQL result, selecting the `Key` would do it.

Comment: @AskYous - `stats.ToString()` will also show you the generated query, if you don't manage to find SQL Profiler.

Comment: @GertArnold Right. So basically you are explaining that apples should not be compared to oranges :)

Comment: Yes, and also that some oranges can look like apples :)